# How to reduce space between two lines of the same bullet point?

Tags: overleaf

I have a bullet point written as:

```
\textbf{Heading}  
\vspace{-0.75em}
 \begin{itemize}
    \itemsep -0.9em  
     \item some random text that takes space of 2 lines.
 \end{itemize}
```

The output:

- The text comes here. The text comes here. The text comes here. The text comes here.The text comes here.The text comes here.The text comes here.The text comes here.

How can I reduce the space between the two lines of a bullet point?

I am trying to make a resume using the template: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/faangpath-simple-template/npsfpdqnxmbc
I have used the bullet points in all the sections. I want to maintain a consistent gap between the bullet points as well as within the bullet points.

Comment: How does this line height adjustment compare to the rest of your document? It's better to maintain some form of consistency, don't you think?

Comment: Just to understand...these two lines are part of the same paragraph and not two separate paragraphs in the same `\item`?  If that's the case, I agree with Werner.  In any event, it would help if you edited your question and provided a small but working example that actually demonstrates the issue (which your example does not).

Comment: I have included the template I am working on, and yes I want to make the whole document consistent, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Please, extend your code fragment to complete small document with your list. In preamble load only packages and your definitions relevant to your problem. Also make your question more clear, what is your problem.  Help us to help you! See documentation for `enumitem` package for option for list customizations.